# Redirect to absolute URL

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to redirect to a tenant sub-domain after registering a tenant in my site but I am receiving a namespace error.

**Views.py:**

```
domain = Domain()
domain.domain = tenant.schema_name + '.localhost:8000'
domain.tenant = tenant
domain.is_primary = False
domain.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(domain.domain))
```

**Error:**

> **NoReverseMatch at /companies/company_registration/**
>   'company.localhost' is not a registered namespace

How do I add a sub-domain, which I do not currently know, as a URL namespace? Or better yet, how to redirect to an absolute URL?

Comment: Try removing the ```reverse``` part of the redirect and use ```HttpResponseRedirect(domain.domain)``` instead. You are getting the error because the reverse function is supposed to take in an app_name like 'blogs:blogs'

Comment: I tried. My browser just gives an alert `Open xdg-open` then does nothing.

Comment: Or you can try the ```redirect()``` function. That is ```redirect(domain.domain)```

Comment: I have also tried that. It does not work.

Comment: are you using django-hosts?

Comment: No, only django-tenant-schemas

Comment: did you add the protocol. ie. "http://". What does the domain.domain return

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not being explicit enough. It was solved by prefixing the URL with the "http://" protocol as @NduJay suggested.

**The simplest solution:**

```
domain.domain = tenant.schema_name + '.localhost'
domain.tenant = tenant
domain.is_primary = False
domain.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://' + domain.domain + ':8000')
```

Comment: You might find `'//' + domain.domain` useful if you want to redirect http->http and https->https.